# How to prevent re-render of react-router-dom Link component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to limit the amounts of components that re-render on my app everytime the user clicks something. Given that the Sidebar renders regardless of which page the user is on, it seems to make sense to wrap it inside a `React.memo` function. This works well and the Sidebar component itself does not seem to re-render. However, the `<Link>` elements, which I import from `react-router-dom` do re-render, as do the `SidebarAuthButtons` and the `SidebarCreateButton`.

What can I do to prevent this behavior?

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  SidebarContainer,
  SidebarLogo,
  SidebarNav,
  SidebarMenu,
  SidebarListItem,
  SidebarButton,
} from "../styles/SidebarStyles";

function Sidebar({ auth }) {
  const SidebarAuthButtons = (
    <div>
      <SidebarButton>
        <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
      </SidebarButton>
      <SidebarButton outlined={true}>
        <Link to="/register">Create Account</Link>
      </SidebarButton>
    </div>
  );

  const SidebarCreateButton = (
    <SidebarButton>
      <Link to="#">Create</Link>
    </SidebarButton>
  );

  return (
    <SidebarContainer>
      <SidebarLogo>React Project</SidebarLogo>
      <SidebarNav>
        <SidebarMenu>
          <SidebarListItem isHeading={true}>Menu</SidebarListItem>
          <SidebarListItem>
            <Link to="/">Explore</Link>
          </SidebarListItem>
          <SidebarListItem>
            <Link to="/blogs">Blogs</Link>
          </SidebarListItem>
          <SidebarListItem>
            <Link to="/podcasts">Podcasts</Link>
          </SidebarListItem>
          <SidebarListItem>
            <Link to="/youtube">Youtube</Link>
          </SidebarListItem>
        </SidebarMenu>
        {auth.isAuthenticated ? SidebarCreateButton : SidebarAuthButtons}
      </SidebarNav>
    </SidebarContainer>
  );
}

export default memo(Sidebar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `SidebarAuthButtons` and `SidebarCreateButton` outside of the functional component render scope making them into React components (currently they are just jsx saved to a variable). This should fix the rerenders.

Comment: Thanks, that helps - do you have any insight on how I could get the same result with the Links?

Comment: Try using the React devtools performance tool to see why the renders are happening. Note that rerenders of a simple Link component are very cheap and this seems to be a bit of premature optimization.